# Proving Gaussian Integers are countable

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, gaussian-integers

I know that Gaussian Integers are a subset of complex numbers. They are numbers in the form

$G = \{a + ib \,\vert\, a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

So to prove that a set is countable, I need to find a function $G \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that every $n$ has finitely many preimages (from [tricki.org](http://www.tricki.org/article/A_good_way_of_proving_that_a_set_is_countable)).

How should I go about proving that it is countable? I don't really understand what preimages mean.

Comment: Same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202646/countability-of-gaussian-integers)

Answer (score 2):

$G$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. In general, the finite cartesian product of countable sets is countable.

If you want an explicit bijection for this problem, here's a hint:
$$0,1,i,-1,-i,1+i,-1+i,1-i,-1-i,2,2i,-2,-2i,\ldots$$

Comment: Why does $G$ have the same cardinality as the cartesian product of $\Bbb Z$?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, since $\Bbb Z[i]=\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\Bbb Z\}$, we have $\vert\Bbb Z[i]\vert=\vert\Bbb Z×\Bbb Z\vert$.

But $\vert \Bbb Z\vert=\vert\Bbb N\vert$.  So $\vert\Bbb Z×\Bbb Z\vert=\vert\Bbb N×\Bbb N\vert$.

Now look at [Cantor's pairing function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) .